# Show that the set $K$ of all constant polynomial in $Z[x]$ is not ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

Please check my proof.

Suppose $K$ is ideal, there must exist $ar,ra$ that generated all constant polynomial.
But any prime constant polynomial can't be generated by any $ra$ because it is irreducible then $K$ is not ideal.

Comment: What happens if you multiply a constant polynomial by $x$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Is x will be  generator ?

Comment: An ideal of a commutative ring $R$ is closed under addition and multiplication, **and also** under multiplication with any element of $R$. If you remove this last condition, it is only a $S$-module, where $S$ is the subring of $R$ generated by $1$.

Comment: Ok i try to understand if I multiply by x then is not closed Am I correct ?

Comment: Down vote??? What wrong ?